# 2 separate UIGestureRecognizer delegates in 2 separate VCs

Tags: ios6, delegates, uigesturerecognizer

I have successfully implemented gesture control in my first VC and have UIGestureRecognizerDelegate in its .h file to identify that specific VC as the delegate for gestures.

So as I approach my second ViewController in the same app - it also needs to support its own gestures.

Q: How to I go about implementing support for the 2nd VC? If I add UIGestureRecognizerDelegate to VC2's .h file, will the app be confused having 2 VCs accepting delegate requests?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. It seems that using different @selector method names is enough to distinguish.